# I can't connect to my AWS server after yum update on centOS 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos7, yum, linux-kernel

I created a new server (EC2) with centOS 7, and after the first "yum update" and a reboot I can't connect anymore.

```
====================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Arch                      Version                                            Repository                            Size
====================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel                                     x86_64                    3.10.0-693.21.1.el7                                updates                               43 M
 mysql-community-libs                       x86_64                    5.6.39-2.el7                                       mysql56-community                    2.0 M
     replacing  mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.56-2.el7
Updating:
 binutils                                   x86_64                    2.25.1-32.base.el7_4.2                             updates                              5.4 M
 cloud-init                                 x86_64                    0.7.9-9.el7.centos.6                               updates                              628 k
 dhclient                                   x86_64                    12:4.2.5-58.el7.centos.3                           updates                              282 k
 dhcp-common                                x86_64                    12:4.2.5-58.el7.centos.3                           updates                              174 k
 dhcp-libs                                  x86_64                    12:4.2.5-58.el7.centos.3                           updates                              130 k
 epel-release                               noarch                    7-11                                               epel                                  15 k
 initscripts                                x86_64                    9.49.39-1.el7_4.1                                  updates                              435 k
 iptables                                   x86_64                    1.4.21-18.3.el7_4                                  updates                              428 k
 iwl7265-firmware                           noarch                    22.0.7.0-58.el7_4                                  updates                              3.5 M
 kernel-tools                               x86_64                    3.10.0-693.21.1.el7                                updates                              5.2 M
 kernel-tools-libs                          x86_64                    3.10.0-693.21.1.el7                                updates                              5.1 M
 kmod                                       x86_64                    20-15.el7_4.7                                      updates                              121 k
 kmod-libs                                  x86_64                    20-15.el7_4.7                                      updates                               50 k
 kpartx                                     x86_64                    0.4.9-111.el7_4.2                                  updates                               73 k
 libdb                                      x86_64                    5.3.21-21.el7_4                                    updates                              719 k
 libdb-utils                                x86_64                    5.3.21-21.el7_4                                    updates                              132 k
 libgcc                                     x86_64                    4.8.5-16.el7_4.2                                   updates                               98 k
 libgomp                                    x86_64                    4.8.5-16.el7_4.2                                   updates                              154 k
 libstdc++                                  x86_64                    4.8.5-16.el7_4.2                                   updates                              301 k
 libteam                                    x86_64                    1.25-6.el7_4.3                                     updates                               47 k
 microcode_ctl                              x86_64                    2:2.1-22.5.el7_4                                   updates                              786 k
 nfs-utils                                  x86_64                    1:1.3.0-0.48.el7_4.2                               updates                              399 k
 python-perf                                x86_64                    3.10.0-693.21.1.el7                                updates                              5.2 M
 selinux-policy                             noarch                    3.13.1-166.el7_4.9                                 updates                              437 k
 selinux-policy-targeted                    noarch                    3.13.1-166.el7_4.9                                 updates                              6.5 M
 systemd                                    x86_64                    219-42.el7_4.10                                    updates                              5.2 M
 systemd-libs                               x86_64                    219-42.el7_4.10                                    updates                              378 k
 systemd-sysv                               x86_64                    219-42.el7_4.10                                    updates                               72 k
 teamd                                      x86_64                    1.25-6.el7_4.3                                     updates                              112 k
 tuned                                      noarch                    2.8.0-5.el7_4.2                                    updates                              234 k
 tzdata                                     noarch                    2018c-1.el7                                        updates                              479 k
 yum                                        noarch                    3.4.3-154.el7.centos.1                             updates                              1.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
 linux-firmware                             noarch                    20170606-58.gitc990aae.el7_4                       updates                               35 M
 mysql-community-common                     x86_64                    5.6.39-2.el7                                       mysql56-community                    257 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================
Install   2 Packages (+2 Dependent packages)
Upgrade  32 Packages
```

When I try to connect via ssh, returns "ssh: connect to host {the ip server here} port 22: Operation timed out".

When I request a screenshot of the instance, it shows:
[image]

Comment: I would try disabling iptables before you did the update. I'd also double check that the public IP hasn't changed - it shouldn't if you reboot the server, only when you stop and start. An elastic IP works around that issue.

Comment: I made sure of that. I'm using Elastic IP and before restarting I checked if iptables was disabled. I don't understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution (and the bug) here:
https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=14585

Copied from the bug report

> Running "yum update" bricks network connectivity for AWS instances
>   which have IPv6 enabled per the AWS docs.
>
> Image is the "CentOS 7 (x86_64) - with Updates HVM" AMI
>
> Unfortunately, if you update a production instance without a snap, you
>   have no console access to try and recover it by disabling IPv6.
>
> Did a lot of testing over the past several days and it seems to be
>   related to cloud-init and the config of the network stack. In the
>   steps to reproduce, there are two scenarios, one where it doesn't work
>   and a workaround which bypasses cloud-init and does work.
>
> Versions of kernel and cloud-init are in the "Steps" dialogue.